# How do I handle a requirement to put a magnifying glass feature onto my Silverlight app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How do I handle a requirement to put a magnifying glass feature onto my Silverlight app?

It is not as easy as one might think.

The previous programmer did it and thought it looked cool.

It works by manipulating the scaling operation.  It is a lot like the zoom feature in a browser.

Anyway, in my program it requires I change the Z level of some of the objects so that they appear on top of other objects in the window.  How do I do that?

The problem is that I have a grid with two rows.  Naturally, in XAML, whatever is listed last, appears "on top" of whatever is described at the top of the XAML page.  Does this make any sense?  If the components in the top part of the grid are scaled up, they hide behind the bottom row.  I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a magnifying glass effect by having two Image objects. The first object contains the original image, the second image has a scale transform and clip geometry applied to it that simulates the magnifying glass. Then as the mouse moves, you need to manipulate the clip geometry, the left and right coordinates of your image. Here is some XAML code that shows the effect I am talking about

```
<Image Width="640" Height="480" Source="myImage.PNG"/>

  <Image Canvas.Left="-500" Canvas.Top="-380" Width="640" Height="480" Source="myImage.PNG">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="3" ScaleY="3"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Clip>
      <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="40" RadiusY="40" Center="320, 240"/>
    </Image.Clip>
  </Image>
```

Also, if that's not enough, [here is a tutorial](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/tutorials/magnifying_glass.aspx) on how to do a magnifying glass effect. And here's [yet another tutorial](http://www.gigyonline.com/code/source/silverlight/MagnifyingGlassEffect.html).

Comment: That is not what I had in mind, but it is, in fact better, I think.

Comment: @xarzu - Sorry. I know you need help with your grid problem. I just thought maybe my post could help in some way.